# Thermal Energy Storage heat loss coefficient

Tags: energy-efficiency, storage, heat

**What I am looking for?**

I am trying to find a source which is stating typical heat loss coefficient of a thermal energy storage or a buffer tank.

**Problem**

Most of the resources I've found so far, rather than stating the heat loss rate in the format of W/m^2k, they are stated in the form of normal standing loss values. This is not helpful in my case where I am using  heat loss equations to estimate the possible losses.

**Aim & objective**

*Aim* The aim of my research is develop an open-source user friendly interface to characterize the output of low emission carbon sources.

*Objective* To characterize the heat loss rate of the storage unit considering the temperature of the water inside the tank.

Note: Formerly, one of the readers replied to a question of mine, that this platform is meant for non-professional individuals having troubles with their home system. I can say that I am a non-professional when it comes to commercial heating systems and I will not have any commercial gain from my project (through your advice).

**Specific Question**

Can you direct me to a source which is stating the **typical** **heat loss** **coefficient** (in **W/m^2.K**) values for thermal energy storage(s) (a.k.a buffer tank) deployed for residential or small commercial sites within the size range of 500 to 5000 liters.

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standby losses you see quoted should conform to a testing standard that would allow deriving the heat loss coefficient.

For hot water storage, I would expect typical tanks to have between 2 and 4 inches of foam insulation, so aged R-Values R10-R12 (hr*ft^2*F/btu)/RSI 1.76-2.11(K*m^2/W) on the low end and double that on the high end, with 2 inches being by far the most common.

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation. Is there any source that you provide so I can use and cite these numbers.

Comment: What do you mean by low end and high end?